# i want to set limit 10 unit my video list with recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, limit

i have a lot of video list, but in my preview page i want to display just 10 videos.

and i will display another video by ***morevideo*** button,

here is my current code :

```
 private void initVideoMusic() {

    LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    rvVideoMusic.setLayoutManager(layout);
    VideoMusicAdapter ar = new VideoMusicAdapter(videoMusic);
    rvVideoMusic.setAdapter(ar);
}
```

and here is my **`Adapter`** that i used to control data `image` & `text` from `API` :

```
public class VideoMusicAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{
static List<VideoMusic> data;

public VideoMusicAdapter(List<VideoMusic> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_premium_video, parent, false);
    return new VH(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    VideoMusic video = data.get(position);
    VH vh = (VH) holder;

    vh.tvArtist.setText(video.alias);
    vh.tvSong.setText(video.judul);
    vh.tvHarga.setText(video.price);
    Picasso.with(vh.imgVideo.getContext())
            .load(video.thumb_pic)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.defaultbg)
            .into(vh.imgVideo);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (data == null) ? 0 : data.size();
}
public class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvArtist;
    TextView tvSong;
    TextView tvHarga;
    ImageView imgVideo;

    public VH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvArtist = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_artist);
        tvSong = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tvHarga = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_harga);
        imgVideo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_video);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used pagination concept here to solve this kind of problem.Follow below link first understand it and implement into your application.

https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/pagination-with-recyclerview-1cb7e66a502b

hope this content useful for you.

```
private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener recyclerViewOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (!isLoading && !isLastPage) {
            if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                    && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
                    && totalItemCount >= PAGE_SIZE) {
                loadMoreItems();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

this above is useful content in loadmoreItem() add your more item into list and notify your data.